# Big O complexity of the cases (answers provided- confirmation would be awesome!)

Tags: linked-list, big-o, complexity-theory, chain

Question:
***We have a chain (or a linked list) of integers with 2-field records: an integer field and a pointer field. If there are n items in a given list, what is the Big O complexity of each of the following cases? -- Note that the chain is not implemented as an array. --***

**Add an item (to the end of the chain)**
*O(1).*
**Add an item (at some position in the chain)**
*O(n).*
**Find whether or not the chain is empty**
*O(1).*
**Check to see if the chain contains a given integer**
*O(n).*
**Get an item (i.e. the integer in the integer field) at some position in the chain**
*O(n).*

I believe the answers that i've got are correct but confirmation from an expert would make my day :) Thank you for your time

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about an actual programming problem.

Comment: @sashoalm sorry mate, i only posted to have an expert confirm if my answers to the questions were correct (since they were) i'll gladly delete the post but can't since an answer has been posted as a response. Have a good day :)

Comment: @user3418449 That's a really, really terrible way of abusing this site - asking a question, waiting for the answers and then removing the question. Downvoted + Flagged.

Comment: @user3418449 No problem, but please read the [FAQ] - carefully - before posting next time. They give examples of what questions are in the scope of this site.

Comment: @user3418449 please vote to close your question instead.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt maybe you should calm down, i don't see anyone getting hurt. And how is it abusing? when I've clearly posted my answers with the question- all of the answers which were correct- and I think the title is specific enough to let users know what the post is about so you don't bother posting silly comments like that of yours. Please vote to remove the post. No one else seems to be as upset as you. it was a simply question and a specific request! thanks for your contribution. I'm a simple guy with a basic life, i've been stressed with my studying and here comes a "downer" like you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an item (to the end of the chain)
O(1).

It depends on the implementation. Usually a classic LinkedList doesn't have a pointer to its last element, so It would be O(n).
If we have a pointer to its last element, so yeah, it would be O(1).

Add an item (at some position in the chain)
O(n).

Correct.

Find whether or not the chain is empty
O(1).

Correct.

Check to see if the chain contains a given integer
O(n).

Correct.

Get an item (i.e. the integer in the integer field) at some position in the chain
O(n).

Correct.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation :)

Comment: I'll update my post to implement both possible answers, cheers :)